# Why does v1SigningEnabled not working for AGP 7.1.3

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, apk-signing

My project's minSdk is 26, AGP is 7.1.3, and when I enable v1 + v2 signature in gradle signing config like this:

```
v1SigningEnabled true
v2SigningEnabled true
```

The final apk contains v2 + v3 signature:

```
Verifies
Verified using v1 scheme (JAR signing): false
Verified using v2 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v2): true
Verified using v3 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v3): true
Verified using v4 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v4): false
```

Is this an AGP bug?

I searched the google issue tracker and seems it was an old version's bug and was announced to be fixed in AGP 4.0.0, seems it come out again.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need v1 enabled since your minimum supported SDK version is 26, which is Oreo Android 8.0. Devices greater than Android 7.0 uses v2 and v3. So there is no issues in my point of view.

Comment: Thank you, yes we don't need it on standard android, but some weird System (modified Android) will check v1 signing. Luckily this issue is resolved by enabled the v1 siging, although the verify tool shows it's v2 + v3, but the system accepted it.